# Is there a possibility to focus on a selected SCNNode

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have the following situation.
A `SCNView` with a `.scn` of a bridge showing.
On the left part of the screen you see the visual representation of the bridge.

I'd like to do the following.

- Select an item on the left in the "model browser"
- Zoom to the selected item and focus on it

[image: Selected item]

On the screenshot provided. You can see I've selected `Kist` which is yellow in the `SceneView`
Now I'd like to zoom and focus on the selected `SCNNode`

I've already tried to use `rayTestWithSegment` to find the selected position to zoom. But the result of `rayTestWithSegment` is always `[]`.

I've also tried to use a `SCNLookAtConstraint` but this doesn't do the trick.

```
    var constraint: SCNLookAtConstraint!

    func handle(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let result = hitTestResult(for: gesture), let world = sceneView?.scene?.physicsWorld else { return }
        let nodePosition = result.node.position
        let results = world.rayTestWithSegment(from: SCNVector3(0, 1, 0), to: nodePosition, options: nil)
        print(results)
        constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: result.node)
        sceneView?.pointOfView?.constraints = [constraint]
    }

    func hitTestResult(for gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) -> SCNHitTestResult? {
        let location = gesture.location(in: sceneView)
        guard let hit = sceneView?.hitTest(location, options: nil), hit.count > 0, let result = hit.first else {
            return nil
        }
        return result
    }
```

I'm using `rayTestWithSegment` because there is the possibility that a `SCNNode` which I've selected is not fully visible. For example an `SCNNode` which is behind another node in this perspective.

Thanks in advance, I hope someone can help / explain me what I'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the [`-[SCNCameraController frameNodes:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncameracontroller/2875846-framenodes) API that should do just that.

Comment: Thanks mnuages! It worked. It focusses on the selected node. Only now sometimes when there is another `scnnode` in front of the selected one. It's not visible. But I might be able to fix that. Thanks for your help!